# How to call DialogExtensions.RunAsync

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, botframework

I am migrating a bot V3 to V4.

I have searched in the internet but I have not found an answer for this.

I would like to call method RunAsync from DialogExtensions Class:

```cs
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   
{
      await DialogExtensions.RunAsync(turnContext,          
      ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState"),                
      cancellationToken);
}
```

This is all code in class:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Bots
{
    public class NewBot : ActivityHandler
    {
        private IMemoryCache Cache;
        protected readonly BotState ConversationState;

        public NewBot(IMemoryCache _cache)
        {
            Cache = _cache;
        }

        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            await DialogExtensions.RunAsync(
                null,
                turnContext,
                ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState"),
                cancellationToken);
        }
        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hello and welcome!"), cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The method RunAsync is requering the parameter dialog (type Dialog).

How can I pass for method this parameter? How can I instantiate the Dialog class?

Comment: Is there any reason you're calling [`RunAsync`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/DialogExtensions.cs#L11) rather than [`BeginDialogAsync`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/14d1e178a7194468c48872e80ac8ec945e560427/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/Dialog.cs#L67)? `BeginDialogAsync`'s second parameter (options) allows for passing in data to the dialog.

Comment: @MattStannett, how can I call BeginDialogAsync? I am new in bot V4. I will edit my question and will put all code in class.

Comment: There is Dialog migration documentation available [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/conversion-framework?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#convert-your-dialogs). Essentially you call `BeginDialogAsync` on your DialogContext  or *StepContext objects. There is in-depth documentation on how Dialogs work in v4 [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).  Take a look at the core bot available [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/e0b02a086ef8d8553fe66a89c92f485252b28e94/samples).

Comment: @MattStannett, I need to exchange this V3 code: `await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new BasicLuisDialog())` for V4 code. Is it correct to use the Dialog in this case? My post is about this exchange!

Comment: No, you do not need to use a dialog in this case. See the [nlp-with-dispatch](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/3cfb7eec6a11f653203781c652245a6288d6286e/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch) sample on how you could achieve this without dialogs. You're probably better off starting with a V4 sample rather than migrating from V3.

Comment: Thank you! I can't start with V4. My job is exchange a big bot in V3 to V4.

Comment: In that case make sure to review the links that I posted above, especially this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/conversion-framework?view=azure-bot-service-4.0.

Comment: @MattStannett, I'm here again to thanks. Today I had success in that case!

Comment: Would you like to post your solution as an answer so you can accept it?

Comment: Yes, but there is no a solutionss code. In this case, there is a documentation posted by Matt that opened my mind! The documentaion is here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/e0b02a086ef8d8553fe66a89c92f485252b28e94/samples

Comment: @MattStannett, I am here again. I migrated the bot from V3 to V4 successfully! Now, in some cases, I need to ask user for more detail. (e.g. user sends for bot the month, and I need the year too) I want to temporarily save month until get the year. In other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57612500/how-to-call-dialog-inside-botframework-v4-in-net-core/57613963?noredirect=1#comment101685107_57613963), a gentle programmer suggested to me to use DialogExtensions.RunAsync. Can you help me in this issue again?

Comment: @LeandroDuarte take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/19.custom-dialogs) which does what you want, especially [this method](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/19.custom-dialogs/Dialogs/RootDialog.cs#L22-L66) and [this method](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/19.custom-dialogs/Dialogs/SlotFillingDialog.cs#L127-L157).

Comment: @MattStannett thank you again. Your tip opened my mind. I am following that way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions is read the documentation [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/e0b02a086ef8d8553fe66a89c92f485252b28e94/samples). It opened my mind!