# How to call dialog inside botframework v4 in net-core?

Tags: botframework, asp.net-core-2.1

I finally migrated a bot from v3 to v4 and it is working. It wouldn't be possible with out this community. Thank you all!

Now I am trying to include dialog in my bot. I've read documentation and have studied samples in github (botframework v4 repository), in this case all samples always start with dialog.

I don't need to start with dialogs because not all messages from the users require dialog. The most of messages from users call Luis and it is enough to unique response.

The issue is:

In some cases, my logic identify that user message requires more details, then I need to start a dialog to ask for more detail. I don't know how to start the dialog after user has sent several messages that doesn't require dialogs in the same session.

Thank you for ever help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use Dialog to process single turn responses. In your case you can process the user input in `OnMessageActivityAsync` from your `ActivityHandler`, run against Luis, then use SendActivityAsync to send response back directly for simple intents, or run `dialog.RunAsync` to start a dialog when needed.

Your simple intents don't have a state, so there is nothing you need to worry about "previous messages".

However, I personally would suggest you start with a parent dialog which handles intent identification and intent processing. By doing that your intent identification/processing logic can be moved out of the `ActivityHandler` and it's easier to add things like authentication.

This does require a bit of code though. I tried to simplify this kind of situation in one of my projects so that bot developers can focus on their business logic. I shared the code on [git hub with some sample](https://github.com/sidecus/zyin.intentbot). If you are interested you can check it out.

Comment: Thanks @sidecus! In some cases, I need to ask for more detail. Example: user sends for bot the month, and I need the year too. I want to temporarily save first month until get the year. Until this moment, I have seen this mechanism in dialog.  You said it is possible if I use dialog.RunAsync. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you talking about Luis entities?

That's where the parent dialog helps. The parent dialog processes the initial message, identifies the intent and known entities (e.g the month), it then starts a child dialog and passes the known entities as "options" by calling ```turnContext.BeginDialogAsync```. Your child dialog then decides what to ask based on the info already collected.

Without a parent dialog you'll have to use bot states by yourself to pass them - not so convenient.

I wanted to add this to my git hub repo as well. Haven't got time but might give it a try over the weekend.

Comment: @LeandroDuarte - actually, you can pass the entities by yourself, but you cannot use the RunAsync extension method. You'll have to handle it by youself by calling ```BeginDialogAsync``` and pass the entities as options instead of null - check the [RunAsync extension method implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/7e1b6acf3ce8e75cbecf2ed899a7168e59fce590/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/DialogExtensions.cs).

Comment: I would still suggest you use a parent dialog though since that's much cleaner and easier.

Comment: Yes, about Luis entities. I understood, but in my bot the code is protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken). And turnContext does not have method BeginDialogAsync.

Comment: Please check the RunAsync extention method link I pasted above - it shows you how to create a dialog and run it via BeginDialogAsync, you just need to pass the right options to the method.

Comment: Ok. I am going to check now!

Comment: I checked. I think my bot is not good. I don't have the parameters (Dialog dialog, ITurnContext turnContext, IStatePropertyAccessor<DialogState> accessor). In this case, Ia can't call the method RunAsync in DialogExtensions. See the code bellow:

Comment: public async Task ShowLuisResult(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, LuisResult result,
            Dictionary<string, string> permissions, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // get recognized entities
            var botEntity = new BotEntityRecognition(result);
            string entityResults = "";

            if (botEntity.entityKpis.ToString() == null)
            {
                //here I need to start a dialog for ask user more details
            }
        }

Comment: Thank you for help me. I will create another post about how to use DialogExtensions.